# Why Next.js does not accept passed function as function?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In ReactJs it works well.

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Snackbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import axios from "axios";
import { withTranslation } from "../../i18n";
import MuiAlert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import sha512 from "crypto-js/sha512";
import { LoginEmailIn, LoginEmailOut } from "../../Types";
import { getTempUserUuid } from "../../util/Utility";
//import ReactPixel from "react-facebook-pixel";
import styles from "../../styles/LoginAndRegistration.module.css";
import {BEUrl} from "../../util/Utility"


function Alert(props: any) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}
function LoginWithEmail({ t },props: {
  eventId: string;
  trackUserInteractions:boolean;
  eventName: string;
  setLogin: (a:boolean)=> void;
}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [alertOpen, setAlertOpen] = useState(false);
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState("");
  const [alertType, setAlertType] = useState("error");
  const alertClose = (event: any, reason: any) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setAlertOpen(false);
  };
  const checkEmail = () => {
    const regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (email === "") {
      setAlertType("error");
      setAlertMessage(t("Please enter your registered e-mail address"));
      setAlertOpen(true);
      return false;
    } else if (!regex.test(email)) {
      setAlertType("error");
      setAlertMessage(t("The entered e-mail address is not valid"));
      setAlertOpen(true);
      return false;
    } else return true;
  };

  const checkPassword = () => {
    if (password === "") {
      setAlertType("error");
      setAlertMessage(t("Please enter your password"));
      setAlertOpen(true);
      return false;
    } else return true;
  };

  const loginButtonPressed = () => {
    if (checkEmail() && checkPassword()) {
      const loginData: LoginEmailIn = {
        email: email,
        passwordHash: sha512(password).toString(),
        tempUserId: getTempUserUuid(),
      };
      let url = BEUrl + "loginEmail";
      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data: loginData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", crossDomain: true },
      })
        .then((resp: any) => {
          const data: LoginEmailOut = resp.data;
          if (!data.error) {
            setAlertType("success");
            setAlertMessage(t(`Successful login, Welcome ${data.userName!}`));
            setAlertOpen(true);
            localStorage.setItem("isRegistrationHappened", "true");
            localStorage.setItem("userNameLoggedIn", data.userName!);
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", data.jwt!);
            setTimeout(function () {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 1200);
          } else {
            setAlertType("error");
            setAlertMessage(t(`${data.error}`));
            setAlertOpen(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
  };

  /*const trackEmailLoginFinished = () => {
    if (useClientSide) {
      if (
        window.location.hostname !== "localhost" &&
        props.trackUserInteractions &&
        !userInteractions.includes(`IA ${props.eventName} EmailLoginFinished`)
      ) {
        ReactPixel.track(`IA ${props.eventName} EmailLoginFinished`, {
          content_ids: [props.eventId],
        });
        userInteractions.push(`IA ${props.eventName} EmailLoginFinished`);
        localStorage.setItem(
          "userInteractions",
          JSON.stringify([...userInteractions])
        );
      }
    }
  };*/

  const [userInteractions, setUserInteractions] = useState();

useEffect(()=> {
  setUserInteractions(JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("userInteractions") ?? "[]"
  ))
},[])

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.loginContainer}>
        <label className={styles.loginInputLabel}>{`${t(
          "Please enter your e-mail address"
        )}`}</label>
        <input
          id="loginMail"
          name="loginMail"
          className="loginInput toLowerCase"
          autoFocus
          type="email"
          onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value.toLowerCase())}
        />
      </div>
      <label className="loginInputLabel">{`${t(
        "Please enter your password"
      )}`}</label>
      <input
        id="loginPassword"
        className="loginInput"
        name="loginPassword"
        type="password"
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <button
          className="loginAndRegButton"
          onClick={() => {
            loginButtonPressed();
            /*trackEmailLoginFinished();*/
          }}
        >
          {t("Login")}
        </button>
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }} className="loginOrRegSwitch">
          {t("You don't have an account yet")}?{" "}
          <a href="#" onClick={() => props.setLogin(false)}>
            {" "}
            {t("Sign up")}
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <Snackbar open={alertOpen} autoHideDuration={3000} onClose={alertClose}>
        <Alert onClose={alertClose} severity={alertType}>
          {alertMessage}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default withTranslation("translate")<any>(LoginWithEmail);
```

Comment: Are you passing a function to the `setLogin` when you are using the exported component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to be:

```
function LoginWithEmail({ t, ...props }) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Hi! Would you explain a bit, why this helps?

Comment: The way you wrote the function, you'd expect two parameters. Some object as the first one and then some other value, that you've called props as the second one. But that's not the case. A functional component only receives one parameter, that is the key-value object props.